# Is it possible to extract a superclass in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to extract a super class from an existing class in my Class Diagram and was wondering if this is possible in Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not out of the box.

But EA comes with a scripting module, so you could script something.